# setInterval timer need offset on animated progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script:

http://jsfiddle.net/bXJhe/7/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    timer(10)

});

// Timer
var GLOBAL_TIMER;

function timer(intCount) {
    GLOBAL_TIMER = setInterval(function() {

        var intTickLength = 10;

        if (intCount < 10) {
            jQuery('#timer').html('00:0' + intCount--);
            jQuery('#bar').css('width', intCount * intTickLength + 'px');
        } else {
            jQuery('#timer').html('00:' + intCount--);
            jQuery('#bar').css('width', intCount * intTickLength + 'px');
        }

        if (intCount < 0) {
          stopTimer();
        }

    }, 1000);
}

function stopTimer() {
    clearInterval(GLOBAL_TIMER);
}​
```

I'm animating the width of the progress bar based on the `intCount` * `intTickLength` (maybe there's a better way?)

Problem is, when the counter reaches 1, the last tick on the bar disappears.  I need it to remain until counter reaches 0. I need some kind of an offset.. Any ideas? I'm no js expert, but I long to be one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the bar size before you decrement the counter:

```
jQuery('#bar').css('width', intCount * intTickLength + 'px');
jQuery('#timer').html('00:0' + intCount--);
```