# setInterval advance to next div when timer has cycled

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I've been fiddling with this:

http://jsfiddle.net/bXJhe/46/

What I need is for the time to advance to the next div id after timer has cycled.  I click on "one" and it shows the current id, then it should advance to "two", "three"... and show their respective ids. I do not want to use jQuery's .remove() or .detach().  Any insight would be fantastic.

Have a big project due, and no hair left to pull out.

HTML:

```
<span id="bar"></span>
<span id="timer">00:05</span>


<div id="one"><a href="#">one</a></div>
<div id="two"><a href="#">two</a></div>
<div id="three"><a href="#">three</a></div>
<div id="four"><a href="#">four</a></div>
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery('div').not(':first').hide();
    jQuery('a').hide();

    timer(5)
});

// Timer
var GLOBAL_TIMER;

function timer(intCount) {
    GLOBAL_TIMER = setInterval(function() {

        var intTickLength = 5;


        jQuery('#bar').css('width', intCount * intTickLength + 'px');
        jQuery('#timer').html('00:0' + intCount--);      


        if (intCount < 0) {

            jQuery('a').show('slow');

             jQuery('a').click(function() {
                 id = jQuery(this).parent('div').attr('id');
                 alert('current id: ' + id);
                 jQuery(this).hide();
                 timer(5);
             });

             stopTimer();
        }

    }, 1000);
}

function stopTimer() {
    clearInterval(GLOBAL_TIMER);
}
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're looking for.  Do you want timer -> show "one" -> click "one" -> hide "one" -> timer -> show "two" -> etc.?

Comment: Ethan...yes. That's exactly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I guess this is what you're looking for [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bXJhe/50/) ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check and see if [this](http://jsfiddle.net/izaiasdotcom/pKMaC/1/) is what you need:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery('div').hide();

    currDiv = jQuery('#one');

    timer(5);
});

// Timer
var GLOBAL_TIMER;

function timer(intCount) {
    GLOBAL_TIMER = setInterval(function() {

        var intTickLength = 5;

        jQuery('#bar').css('width', intCount * intTickLength + 'px');
        jQuery('#timer').html('00:0' + intCount--);

        if (intCount < 0) {

            currDiv.show('slow');

             currDiv.click(function() {
                 id = currDiv.attr('id');
                 alert('current id: ' + id);
                 jQuery(this).hide();

                 currDiv = currDiv.next();
                 timer(5);
             });


             stopTimer();
        }

    }, 1000);
}

function stopTimer() {
    clearInterval(GLOBAL_TIMER);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest solution, I think, is to use jQuery's `data()` mechanism to attach a variable to each `<div>`, signaling that it's the next one to be shown.

Also, you have `<a>` elements inside your `<div>` elements, and you're sometimes trying to show/hide one or the other...it seems to me it would be clearer to always operate on the same element.  I chose the `<div>` elements.

So, first you'll want to hide all your `<div>` elements:

```
jQuery('div').hide();
```

Then you'll want to indicate that the "one" `<div>` is the next one to be shown:

```
jQuery('#one').data('nextToBeShown',true);
```

Then when you're going through each element (I go through `<div>`s instead of `<a>`s), you just have to look to see if it's the next element to be shown, and show it:

```
jQuery('div').each(function() {
    current = jQuery(this);
    if( current.data('nextToBeShown') ) {
        current.show('slow');
    }
});
```

Finally, when you click on the link, you'll want to move the "nextToBeShown" pointer:

```
jQuery('a').click(function() {
    id = jQuery(this).parent('div').attr('id');
    alert('current id: ' + id);
    div = jQuery(this).parent();
    div.hide();
    div.data('nextToBeShown',false);
    div.next().data('nextToBeShown',true);
    timer(9);
});
```

And that gets you where you want....  See my updated jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/NjUg2/1/

Answer (score 0):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ewayus/9/edit)*

Referring to my **[old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12335030/setinterval-timer-need-offset-on-animated-progress-bar)** and my old **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ewayus/5/edit)** to you....

the only thing you need to add is this:

```
////////////// old answer :  
(function($){ // remap "$" to jQuery
$(function(){ // "Document Ready" shorthand
  
  var divCounter = 0;    ///// added

  function timer(bar, intCount){  
     var elWidth = $(bar).width(), intTickLength=intCount, i;  
     function math(){
       var m = Math.floor(intCount/60);
       var s = intCount % 60;
       if(m<10){m='0'+m;}
       if(s<10){s='0'+s;}
       $(bar).next('.timer').text(m+':'+s);
       $(bar).width( elWidth*intCount/intTickLength );
       if(intCount--<=0){         
         clearInterval(i);
         showDiv();  /////// added
       }
     }
     math();
    
     i = setInterval(math, 1000);  
  }  
  timer('#bar',5); 
  ////////////////////////////////

  ///////////// new answer :  
  $('div.box').hide();  // hide all initially 
  function showDiv(){
      $('.box').hide().eq(divCounter%$('.box').length).show();
  }
  
  $('.box a').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.box').hide();
      divCounter++;
      timer('#bar',5);
  });
  /////////////////////////////

});
})(jQuery);
```

HTML: **add a class `.timer` to your span**

```
<span id="bar"></span>
<span class="timer">00:05</span>
```

**and add a common CLASS to your div elements:**

```
<div class="box"><a href="#">one</a></div>
<div class="box"><a href="#">two</a></div>
<div class="box"><a href="#">three</a></div>
<div class="box"><a href="#">four</a></div>
```

If you have questions feel free to ask, and don't pull more hair out, but review some old questions for some solutions :)